# SQL Server: can SecurityAdmin role read error log?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have read, e.g from here

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Find_Out_Server_Roles_For_a_SQL_Server_Login

that SecurityAdmin role can read Error logs. I'm on SecurityAdmin role and when I try to execute xp_readerrorlog I get a following error:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure xp_readerrorlog, Line 1
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_readerrorlog', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

What I'm missing? Can this role read error logs or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SecurityAdmin role can call sp_readerrorlog but not xp_readerrorlog because the role does not allow for using extended stored procedures. No big deal, just have three fewer parameter filters.